# What does "salt to what you’re spouting off." mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> You must show your readers through dialogue, pictures and facts. No matter how great your opinion is or how knowledgeable you are, you still need to show your readers **there’s salt to what you’re spouting off**.

What does "salt to what you’re spouting off." mean in above sentence?

Comment: Check this out: [salt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/salt) "7. Sharp lively wit."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give a boring lecture, the listeners will sleep. But if you have *salt* in it, it becomes **more interesting.**

**Also,** the noun has its similar idiomatic usage.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/add-salt-to-sth) has an entry for that

> add salt to something - *If you add salt to a subject or conversation, you make it more interesting*

Food without salt lacks taste. Adding it makes it tastier. Likewise, a dull lecture can be made interesting by *having* 'salt' in it. That's what your question is. No matter how great knowledge you show, you must have 'salt' in it to make it interesting to the readers.